# How to access an xml with svg content and inject it in the dom

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to inject into the dom an svg that relies in a node_modules's svg file.
the file is under node_modules\react-twemoji-picker\src\twemoji.svg.
It's actually a sort of xml file which looks like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><style>svg{display:none}svg:target{display:inline}</style></defs><svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" id="0023-fe0f-20e3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path.....
```

When trying to import that file :

```
import localtwemoji from "./twemoji.svg";
console.log("localtwemoji ? :", localtwemoji);  // this logs : "static/media/twemoji.8b3c136fba460302b57fc60ff8b592ca.svg"
```

i'm getting a string

> "static/media/twemoji.8b3c136fba460302b57fc60ff8b592ca.svg"

and when i try to fetch it :

```
fetch("./twemoji.svg")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("EmojiComponent ~ response ? :", response);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.");
      });
```

I'm getting such as response which doesn't have any of the real svg content :
[image]

The module itself is setting svg links in src of the images it generates which has the following format :

```
http://localhost:3000/static/media/twemoji.8b3c136fba460302b57fc60ff8b592ca.svg#1fa72
```

and when i open such as url in the browser , i see the svg with the id specified in that url displayed but I also found all the other svgs which are content of the whole xml too there as shown in this image:

[image]

So how to deal with such as xml file and how to access its content and use it in my dom?

Cheers

Comment: you are missing **how** you want to fetch that to start with ... `fetch(resource).then(body => body.text()).then(result => {})` would be a starting point ... pick one [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods) and re-think/write your question?

Comment: Thanks @AndreaGiammarchi. You could write your comment as an answer to this question. I expected to get the svg dom element instead that's why I didn't consider using .text() and it seems not possible by reading that documentation but a string is good too anyway

Comment: done with extra hints 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the *how* part of the *fetch* dance: "*how do you want to fetch that resource?*"

There are [various options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods) but nothing is *DOM* related as *DOM* and network are two different worlds.

Your best option is to use:

```js
fetch(resource)
  .then(body => body.text())
  .then(svg => (new DOMParser)
                 .parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml'))
  .then(actualSVG => {
    // append to the body or do your thing
  });
```

This is one way, another one could be to use a `body.blob()` and then create a resource with that `image/svg+xml` mime type and use it as `new Image().src = urlResource` but this is another story, your issue starts from *not* accessing the body of the response.

Comment: C'mon Andrea, if anyone should suggest a Web Component (not built on any dependencies), it should be you!  Here is my version of a [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) demonstrating it with SVGs